# Pass a service as an @Input() parameter to a child component

Tags: angular

Is it correct that the `@Input()` decorator is designed for data passing only?

Currently, we're reviewing a way of implementing a layout that accepts services (they will implement an interface) as an `@Input` parameter.

Are there some pitfalls we should be aware of?

**Edit**:

I've implemented it with the `providers` property of base classes and `constructor(@Inject ...)` of the child. Here is a complete [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dqzlzu?file=src/app/checks-layout/checks-layout.component.ts). Thank y'all.

Comment: Why use a service for an input? Why can't you pass it to the constructor?

Comment: @Input is for passing data between parent component and child component, why would you use it to pass service? if it is injected in the parent you can inject it in the child.

Comment: Create a service `MyService` (without `providedIn: 'root'`), then create a component that `provides: [MyService]`. Child components that inject that service will use  the parent's service.

Comment: We use a single child to display different services

Comment: It is a good solution.
You can simplify ChecksLayoutComponent construcot like that : 

`
constructor(private service: IChecksService) {}
`

Angular will automatically retrieve the IChecksService instance created by the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Create a service that isn't provided in the root like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  // Class functionality here...
}
```

Create a component that provides the service (this will provide the service to the children). Everytime this component is created an instance of my service will be created as well for this component and its children.

```js
@Component({
  template: '<child></child>',
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class ParentComponent { }
```

Next create the child components (we don't need a provider here since it was provided in the parent).

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: ''
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private readonly myService: MyService) { }
}
```

Comment: The point is we have a single child to display results of various services it accepts as a parameter from parent callers